# How do I backup a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Optimal way to make MySQL backups for fairly large databases (MyISAM / InnoDB)](https://serverfault.com/questions/139593/optimal-way-to-make-mysql-backups-for-fairly-large-databases-myisam-innodb)

What is the best way to backup a MySQL database?  Is there a way to automate that process?

Comment: Please give some more information. How is anybody supposed to answer this like that. What operating system? Is it a remote or local server? Where do you want to do the backup to?

Answer (score 1):

`mysqldump --opt --all-databases | gzip > /path/to/backup/mysql.$(date -Ihour).sql`

To automate it just add it to your crontab. But the comments are right, if you give us some more info, we can give a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Administrator provides easy backup and restore capabilities, and it's free.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php will perform an export of your databases.