# MySQL database backups to a local server

Tags: mysql, backup, database-backup

We have a backup system at the moment, but after a recent scare, we’d like another backup of just the MySQL databases, nightly, to a local server in our office.

The databases are pretty big as it stores a lot of different ecommerce stores. To make things easier for us to find them, rather than just get one giant SQL file, a file of each database would be ideal.

- The web server is CentOS with PHP/MySQL, with access via FTP/SSH
- The local server is Ubuntu with PHP/MySQL, with access via SSH
- Both servers have dedicated IP addresses
- Only the previous day’s database needs to be kept, so it can be overwritten upon success

Any suggestions on the best way to do this?

Comment: I would suggest an rsync script and a naming convention for each of your databases which allows you to uniquely identify each dump'ed dbase and possibly backup into a hierarchical folder structure too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Optimal way to make MySQL backups for fairly large databases (MyISAM / InnoDB)](http://serverfault.com/questions/139593/optimal-way-to-make-mysql-backups-for-fairly-large-databases-myisam-innodb)

Comment: (there are lots of dulpicates of this question - the link I provided has links to some of the others)

Answer (score 1):

```
for db in `mysql -uUsername -pPassword -sN -e "show databases"`
do mysqldump -uUsername -pPassword $db |/usr/bin/bzip2>/backup/$db.sql.bz2
done
```

This command will dump every database to a separate file. You will only have to copy the resulting files to the local server.

Comment: I think you need a space between `-u` and `Username`. Alternatively, put user/pass in your `.my.cnf`

Comment: No, the space is not required here (but possible).